# Why are you able to swap eth to token lesser than specified amount in amountOutMinimum?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, foundry

I am using Dai as an example for token address in constructor so when you call this function it should swap ether to Dai.

My question is why sending ether lesser than amountOutMinimum. It still able to swap? Shouldn't it revert?

```
    function getTokenFromEth(
        address destinationAddress,
        uint256 minAmountOut
    ) external payable override returns (uint256) {
        if (destinationAddress == address(0)) revert InvalidAddress();
        if (msg.value == 0) revert InputCantBeZero();

        ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams({
            deadline: block.timestamp + MAX_DEADLINE,
            tokenIn: WETH9Address,
            tokenOut: Token,
            fee: PoolFee,
            recipient: destinationAddress,
            amountIn: msg.value,

            amountOutMinimum: minAmountOut, 
            sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0 
        });
        uint256 amountOut = uniswapV3Router.exactInputSingle{value: msg.value}(params);

        emit EthExchangedForToken(msg.value, amountOut);
        return amountOut;
```

Test Case:

```
    function test_getTokenFromEth() public {
        address alice = makeAddr("alice");
        vm.deal(alice,10 ether);
        vm.startPrank(alice);
        (bool success, bytes memory bal)= address(uniswapv3).call{value:1 ether}(abi.encodeWithSignature("getTokenFromEth(address,uint256)", alice, 10 ether));
        uint256 result = abi.decode(bal,(uint256));
        uint256 alice_zeta_balance = zetaToken.balanceOf(alice);
        uint256 swap_contact_balance = address(uniswapv3).balance;
        assertEqUint(alice_zeta_balance,result);
        console2.log("alice_zeta_balance", alice_zeta_balance);
        console2.log("swap_contact_balance", swap_contact_balance);

    }
```

Output:

````
    │   ├─ emit EthExchangedForToken(amountIn: 1000000000000000000 [1e18], amountOut: 2068718743231287765901 [2.068e21])
    │   └─ ← 2068718743231287765901 [2.068e21]
    ├─ [602] 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F::70a08231(000000000000000000000000328809bc894f92807417d2dad6b7c998c1afdac6) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000070253d606d5d6fab8d
    ├─ [0] console::log(alice_zeta_balance, 2068718743231287765901 [2.068e21]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] console::log(swap_contact_balance, 0) [staticcall]
    ```
````

Comment: `amountOutMinimum = 10e18` means you'll get at least 10 DAI (since it has 18 decimals). So it's ok that it doesn't revert

Comment: Oh make sense. :P